# mySQL Database. Own Website finds it, external programs not?

Tags: php, mysql, database, unity-game-engine, web

so I'm creating a website right now where I have a mySQL Database included and I'm displaying some tables of it on my website (with PHP) and it works fine.

But now I'm trying to access the database in another program (Unity) to edit my database.I get the error that the host name wasn't found. Then I tried to ping the ip (given from my hoster 1&1) via the Windows console, but not found. mySQL Workbench doesn't find it either.

I'm wondering if I have to set the database to public or something like that when I want to access it from another program. My Website can access it, probably because it's hosted on the same account.

But I only got a hostname, username, password and database name. The hostname is something like that: "db123456789.db.1and1.com". My domain is of course not this. Do I have to change the host name? On my php website script I used this host name and it works fine.

I'm kind of confused how this works and I can't find any option where I could say like "Hey DB, show yourself to the public".

Any tips? Searched the World Wide Web, but didn't found a hint. Thank you.

Comment: https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/administration-c37694/enable-remote-connections-to-mysql-a781586.html

Comment: It probably depends on your hosting provider. I would imagine many block direct access by default as it is generally speaking not a good idea from a security standpoint.

Comment: Would it not be better and much more secure to create an API that your Unity app can communicate with?

Comment: Raphael, thanks for the link but my problem just went bigger. I tried to access my site via ssh with Putty, but it didn't let me type anything so I couldn't login. Now I have the problem that I can't acces my site anymore. It's blocked for my network. I checked it with mobile internet and it works. What the hell did that program do? Sorry for the stupid questions, but I'm new to web development, only coded "offline" before